# Linking HTML and CSS files

Tags: html, css

What will happen if I don't add type and rel in my link element?  If I only add href to link CSS file with HTML? 
My website transformed and I got no error.  Why is it necessary to add type and rel?

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question by trying it out and seeing the result. So not sure what your question is for. Just read up about the link tag online if you want to know more about it.

Comment: Latest forums about the topic suggest that in 2016 its obsolete and there is no need to write type="text/css" anymore.
http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/

Comment: There's different types of `<link/>` 's, for example favicons, so you tell the browser what kind of link you are going to implement. since html5 you only need the `rel`and shouldn't need the type attr any longer. the bare minimum is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

Answer (score 0):

> if I don't add type

The browser will lose the opportunity to reject the stylesheet as being written in a style language it doesn't support before it downloads it.

This isn't a problem for CSS as CSS support is ubiquitous. It is more of an issue for other languages such as LESS.

> and rel in my link element?

The browser won't know what type of relationship the link is (is it a styleheet? Is it the same document in a format other that HTML (such as Atom)? is it a version of the document in a different language? Is it an index page for the collection of documents that this document is a member of?), so it won't download the resource (or do anything else with it) automatically.